# Наследование, проблема с производным классом и динамич. массивом

Tags: c++, классы, память

Столкнулся с одной темой, которую никак не получается разобрать. Имеется следующий кусок кода с базовым классом `Array` и методом `Input`, в котором и кроется ошибка:

```
class Array {
public:
    int *Mass, index;
    Array() {
        index = 0;
    }

    virtual void summ(Array Data) {}
    virtual void foreach() {}
    void Input();
};

void Array::Input() {
    cout << "Массив : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        cin >> Mass[i];
    }
}
```

Также имеется производный класс:

```
class SortArray : public Array {
public:
    SortArray() {}
    SortArray(int arrSize) {
        index = arrSize;
        int *Mass = new int[arrSize];
    }
    void summ(Array Data);
    void foreach();
};
```

При попытке выполнить метод `Input`, для ввода чисел в массив производного класса возникает ошибка, поскольку память под динамический массив похоже была удалена, либо что - то другое. Где искать ошибку? Пробовал перекинуть сами методы, массив, изменять конструктор, но этот динамический массив так и выдает ошибку чтения. Как переработать код? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
int arrSize;
    cout << "Введите размер первого массива: ";
    cin >> arrSize;
    SortArray Arr1(arrSize);
    Arr1.Input();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот здесь

```
int *Mass = new int[arrSize];
```

вы выделили память, но указатель на нее сохранили не в поле класса, а в локальной переменной... И при выходе из конструктора, понятно, ее потеряли.

И еще - не оставляйте неинициализированных переменных. Например,

```
Array() {
    index = 0;
}
```

чему после этого равен `Mas`? Мусору.

Впрочем, вообще вызывает недоумение - `Array` нигде ни разу не инициализирует `Mas`, но функция `Input` - именно в нем... Почему вы спроектировали иерархию именно так?

Comment: Кажется разобрался. Спасибо.